# lateinit property mock object has not been initialized

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, mocking

I'm trying to initialize (by mocking) two objects with the annotation @MockBean

It seems only to work if i call the method mock(className), but since i want to use the mocked class on multiple methods i don't want to keep repeating the same code in my test methods.

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class WordServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    lateinit var wordRepositoryMock: WordRepository

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var wordMapperMock: WordMapper

    @Test
    fun findAllTest() {
        // Error: lateinit property wordRepositoryMock has not been initialized
        val wordService = WordService(wordRepositoryMock, wordMapperMock)
        `when`(wordRepositoryMock.findAll()).thenReturn(listOf(
                WordEntity(UUID.randomUUID(), "xxx"),
                WordEntity(UUID.randomUUID(), "xxx")))
        assertEquals(2, wordService.findAll().size)
    }

    @Test
    fun wordExistsTest() {
        // This works fine
        val wordRepositoryMock = mock(WordRepository::class.java)
        val wordMapperMock = mock(WordMapper::class.java)
        val wordService = WordService(wordRepositoryMock, wordMapperMock)
        val word = "xxx"
        `when`(wordRepositoryMock.existsWordEntityByName(word)).thenReturn(true)
        assertEquals(true, wordService.wordExists(word))
    }
}
```

I don't want to use the Spring Boot @Autowired annotation because my spring application requires  contexts which i don't want to load.

The error i'm getting:

```
lateinit property wordRepositoryMock has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property wordRepositoryMock has not been initialized
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2")
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2"
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.0.0")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.11.3"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.2.7.RELEASE"
    runtimeOnly('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.3.3"
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling initMocks method in setUp()

```
@BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I received this message when using this suggestion:

"'initMocks(Any!): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java"

Comment: In case someone is still wondering, @BrunoCarneiro you got that warning because you were trying to use initMocks instead of openMocks

Comment: initMocks() is deprecated now, you have to use openMocks() as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789353/1820599

Answer (score 13):

`MockitoJUnitRunner` works with the `@Mock` annotation.

`@MockBean` is coming from Spring so you need to use the `@SpringRunner`.

However, it looks like your examples don't need Spring, so you can switch to `@Mock`:

```kotlin
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class WordServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var wordRepositoryMock: WordRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var wordMapperMock: WordMapper
}
```

There's a further improvement you could make if you upgraded to Junit5 (I only tested it in Junit5). Constructor arguments are a good alternative to `lateinit`:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class WordServiceTest(
    @Mock val wordRepositoryMock: WordRepository,
    @Mock val wordMapperMock: WordMapper
) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hovering over MockitoExtension::class gives me the following error: ```Type mismatch.
Required:
KClass<out Runner!>
Found:
KClass<MockitoExtension>``` Which dependencies do you use?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)`

Comment: Ye i figured out that but i'm getting the following error now: ```org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests```

See updated post for my gradle dependencies

Comment: If you're trying to now upgrade junit, than this has become a totally different problem ;) the `@Test` annotation is in a different package. Be careful not to mix the two. I'd try to make it work with the existing version first (my first example).

Not tried it, but perhaps the following would also work?

```@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class WordServiceTest(
    @Mock val wordRepositoryMock: WordRepository,
    @Mock val wordMapperMock: WordMapper
) {

}```

Comment: Well i tried both and both give different errors. With the first version i'm getting the error: ```kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException``` using @Test of package: ```import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test```

Comment: FWIW, it's the c-tor injection that's the real solution here, both for `@Mock` and `@MockBean` - works out of the box, no magic needed

Answer (score 11):

For the ones coming because `initMocks(this)` is deprecated, I noticed there's a newer function that does the same:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        ....
}
```